# Find a string and replace with corresponding value

Tags: excel, replace

Is it possible to find a particular sentence in Excel and replace it with the contents of another cell? I can't use the find and replace function as every cell is different.

For example:

```
     A             B
Canon iP7240    iPad Air
```

So now I'd like to search "**Canon iP7240 - A4 Printer**" and it must automatically change to what is written in Cell B.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the search and replace dialog, on the "replace with" just write the =+the desired cell.
For example:
replace with: =A2.
Hope this is what you where asking for.

Comment: Have you tested that? It does not work when only part of the cell matches.

Comment: This does not work. it changes the desired text into "=A2" for example. basically i have an html string in the cell and i want that string to be changed based on what is displayed in the column next to that html string column.